# Too many arguments in an "if" clause, in jupyter notebook and python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

There seem be too many arguments in my `if` clause. Is it because I'm using strings?

Here's a version of the code:

```
gender = []

for f in full_text:
    if any (["He" in f, "boy" in f, "him" in f, "his" in f]):
        gender.append(0)
    elif any (["She" in f, "girl" in f, "her" in f, "hers" in f]):
        gender.append(1)
    else:
        gender.append(-1)
```

This prints only 0's and -1's even though their are many females in `full_text`.

I get a "correct" result, including 1's, if I run just one male and female statements (and not all males and females are caught):

```
for f in full_text:
    if "He" in f:
        gender.append(0)
    elif "She" in f:
        gender.append(1)
    else:
        gender.append(-1)
```

Here is a sample of `full_text`:

```
full_text = ["This is Phineas. He's a mystical boy. Only eve...", 
             "This is Tilly. She's just checking pup on you....",
             "This is Archie. He is a rare Norwegian Pouncin...",
             "This is Darla. She commenced a snooze mid meal...",
             "Hello"]
```

There should be 1's wherever `She` (or any of the other female pronouns) occurs.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is an example `full_text` data set,and what do you expect the output to be with that dataset?

Comment: Do you have an example of a string that should get an 1 with the first version, but doesn't? It seems OK to me.

Comment: Your code looks fine `f = "He said she said"; any (["He" in f, "boy" in f, "him" in f, "his" in f]) gives True`. You need to post us an example of failing input ([MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: Also, your code needs to define `gender`. We assume it's a list, not a string. (You could use a list-comprehension `gender = [infer_gender(word) for word.lower() in full_text]` rather than iteratively `gender.append()`, but that's a stylistic point)

Comment: You should also lower both compared text, with your example "he is English", won't be detect has male gender.

Comment: Please show a complete code snippet that we can run that shows your problem. In other words, please read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, it's useful to know what you're iterating over: strings or lists; sentences, paragraphs, documents or what? So instead of `for f in full_text:` write e.g. `for para in in full_text:` or `for word in full_text:` Basically don't call your variable `f` unless it's actually a file, which this clearly isn't. Call it something short that describes/suggests what it is.

Comment: Still waiting for your MCVE. So anyway: `gender = [infer_gender(doc) for doc.lower() in full_text]` . Or `para` for paragraph. Or `sent` for sentence.

Comment: Oh here's another style improvement: `if any (male_term in doc for male_term in male_terms)`.

Comment: @Kamori @smci A sample of `full_text` is now listed above.

Comment: @Kamori I put the sample in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas on what could cause problems:

- If the sentence is "She is with him", the output will be 0. is that what you want?
- "she", "her" and "hers" include "he"

Assuming `f` is a string containing multiple words separated by spaces, you should consider lowering the text and splitting the words:

```
for f in full_text:
    words = f.lower().split(" ")
    if any (["he" in words, "boy" in words, "him" in words, "his" in words]):
        gender.append(0)
    elif any (["she" in words, "girl" in words, "her" in words, "hers" in words]):
        gender.append(1)
    else:
        gender.append(-1)
```

Comment: This worked, after I took out `lower()`! That would include the `she`'s.

Comment: Why don't we do `in words` for each of the results?

Comment: @rachelvsamuel right, it should be `in words` everywhere, I messed up my copying and pasting! I edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

For each `f`, your if-statement does the first check of `any (["He" in f, "boy" in f, "him" in f, "his" in f])`, and if that condition is `True`, `0` is appended to `gender`, and your code goes to the next `f` without executing the `elif` portion, so a `1` will never be appended. I've changed it to check word-by-word by splitting `f` into a list. I also needed to add he's/she's to the checks because splitting by spaces doesn't handle contractions well.

```
for f in full_text:
    found = False
    for word in f.lower().split(" "):
        if word in ["he", "boy", "him", "his", "he's"]:
            found = True
            gender.append(0)
        elif word in ["she", "girl", "her", "hers", "she's"]:
            found = True
            gender.append(1)
    if not found:
        gender.append(-1)
```

Comment: This gave 7 results when there should been five. I ran it on the following data set: full_text = ["This is Phineas. He's a mystical boy. Only eve...",  "This is Tilly. She's just checking pup on you....", "This is Archie. He is a rare Norwegian Pouncin...", "This is Darla. She commenced a snooze mid meal...","Hello"]

Comment: Ah, I figured it out `he` registered both `he` and `she`.

Comment: Oops, it still gives seven values.

Comment: I've amended the answer based on your responses.

Comment: It doesn't work. The 0's and 1's don't correlate with the df.